# Macro broke after re-boot - Excel unable to locate external text files

Tags: vba, excel

As part of a larger macro Excel retrieves .dat files from a folder. After a crash and rebooting, the macro no longer works and seizes up upon trying to refresh.

[image]

There was also changes in security upon reboot where I had to enable all macros to be able to step though this current one.

I have double checked to make sure the path is correct and the files are still there.

Updated code and ended up crashing for unrelated memory issue. Fixed the memory problem and now won't run and is giving the same error code and message as before even with updated code. Current code which will run through the first loop but fails on the second.

[image: Error2]

Comment: Is `F:` a mapped network drive? What happens when you refresh the data source?

Comment: it is not, it is on my computer. All of the files are still in that same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, Dir just returns the filename found within that directory and not the full path to that file. What likely happened is your directory was initially set to F: so the macro used this as the default path when searching for the file. The best way to do this would be to store your directory in a constant string, and then append the two together. Something like this:

```
Const fPath as String = "F:YourPathHere\"
strFile = fPath & Dir(fPath & "*.dat")
Debug.Print strFile ' Just to make sure it is setting properly.
```

Comment: I hope it works :). I edited the constant assignment though since the syntax was wrong.

Comment: So I ran my macro through and it crashed due to memory issues. I fixed the memory issue but now it's giving me the same error as before again. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm that Debug.Print strfile returns the correct path?

Comment: Also, I just noticed you are using a "Do While" loop. Is there any reason for this? Unless you have some kind of delay in your code you will run into an infinite loop that will almost immediately use all of the available processing power. I also dont see why someone would need to refresh a data file so frequently. Have you tried using a simple "If" block to call the refresh, and perhaps an "OnTime" command from another sub to call the macro every so often?

Comment: The path is correct, it will do the loop once and then crashes on the second file, even if I remove the first file it will loop once and crash on second attempt with the same error message. made sure all the code is identical to the working version and no dice. pretty frustrating stuff.

Comment: Do while is for the loop to run until it has ran through all the files in the folder.

Comment: Can you post your entire code instead of just the picture? It is hard to see what is causing the crash without the full code. Also, look into using a For loop instead of while. You should be able to do something like "For each fPath in Dir" or something of the sort.

Comment: Should have posted it all out of the gates, it ended up being an error at the end of loop where I needed to add the filepath to the strfile.  Thanks for your time though.